# ERROR: must be owner of materialized view PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-views

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of materialized view mv_sessions
SQL state: 42501
```

When trying to refresh my materialized view:

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY partners.mv_sessions;
```

The owner of `mv_sessions` is my custom `master` user. And I've assigned all privileges to the sub user `partner` with which I'm trying to refresh the view.

I do not want to make `partner` the owner of `mv_sessions`. And also there are other sub users that will need to be able to refresh the view.

---

I tried with a trigger function:

```
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY partners.mv_sessions;
    RETURN NULL;
END
```

Getting the same error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: must be owner of materialized view mv_sessions
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY partners.mv_sessions"
PL/pgSQL function partners.refresh_mv_sessions() line 3 at SQL statement
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) does state "To execute this command you must be the owner of the materialized view". See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171933/142848) for a workaround.

Comment: @Marth So I’m supposed to create 3 MVs which are the same in order to be able to access them with the 3 separate users?

Comment: No. Read (access) permissions are not the same as refresh permissions. You can grant multiple users read-access to the same materialized view, but only the owner(s) will be able to trigger a refresh. Or you can try the solution in the answer I linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function causing the problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partners.refresh_mv_sessions()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY partners.mv_sessions;
    RETURN NULL;
END $$;
```

A fix using `SECURITY DEFINER` according to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171932/postgresql-9-3-13-how-do-i-refresh-materialised-views-with-different-users/171933#171933) (as suggested by Marth) so that a non-owner can refresh a materialized view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partners.refresh_mv_sessions()
RETURNS TRIGGER
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY partners.mv_sessions;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Never create a `SECURITY DEFINER` function without `SET search_path = ...`. It happens to be safe here, though.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you please elaborate on the `search_path`?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY